# Thomae's function and intervals of irrationals

Tags: calculus, continuity, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I have recently stumbled across the [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function?wprov=sfti1), and the most interesting trait of this function are (obviously) its discontinuities. Still, I'm amazed by the converse: this function is actually *continuous* at irrationals.

My calculus background could be wider, and I know very little of $\mathbb{R}$'s properties, or set theory other than the naive version. I know that, by the definition of continuity of a function, there must be some interval around an irrational number where there are only irrational numbers, no matter how small. This would satisfy the definition:
$$\lim_{x\to{x_0}} T(x) = T(x_0) = 0$$
But here's the point. Stating that there is an interval between rationals that only contains irrationals is something I can't quite rationalize (no pun intended), mostly because one proves easily that there's no such thing as "the next rational number".

I'm certain this relates to the density of irrationals in $\mathbb{R}$, but how does "deeper" mathematics (deeper as in, any theory concerning the problem at hand) handle this situation? Is there really an interval of irrationals between every rational, or am I missing something?

Comment: Within any non-empty interval of real numbers, there are included both infinitely many rationals *and* infinitely many irrationals.  Both the set of rational numbers and the set of irrational numbers are dense in the real numbers.  It isn't that in a small enough neighborhood around an irrational point that all values of the function are zero, it is that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a small enough neighborhood around any irrational point that all values of the function are strictly less than $\epsilon$.  The wiki page you linked to already has a rather well written proof on this included.

Comment: My background in calculus is not wide enough to understand wether the proof given in that page does answer my question or not. This is why I'm here. It's not like I dislike the proof or anything.

Comment: This being said, does the proof rely on the fact that one may always find in that neighborhood $1/q, q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that in $1/q < \epsilon$?

Comment: It is the reverse, the proof *shows* (*and does not -rely- on*) that *any* point in the neighborhood is either irrational and so maps to zero, or is rational of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ with $p\in \Bbb Z$ and $q\in\Bbb N^+$ where $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $\frac{1}{q}<\epsilon$ and so maps to a value strictly less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: I could use better terminology, by "relying on" I meant that the focal point of the proof would be *showing* that result to be true. Not as in, "takes the assumption that".

Comment: Even ignoring the discrepancy of the phrase "rely on" you wrote it where $q$ was a rational number.  The way you wrote it i'm rather certain is untrue, for a given epsilon you aren't guaranteed to find a rational number $q$ in a given interval such that $\frac{1}{q}<\epsilon$.  It is important to remember how the function *acts* in the first place.  For example $f(0.8)=f(\frac{4}{5})=\frac{1}{5}$ and $f(0.81)=f(\frac{81}{100})=\frac{1}{100}$.  Similarly $f(0.809987)=f(\frac{809987}{1000000})=\frac{1}{1000000}$ and so on.

Comment: The idea being, the more digits we include in the decimal representation of a particular irrational number, the smaller and smaller we get.  But beyond that, not only looking at numbers of the form $\frac{p}{10^k}$ in the neighborhood, we can also go further and prove that *any* number in a small enough interval will act similarly and output small enough numbers.  Full details are included in the proof linked on the wiki page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no interval $(a,b)\subset\mathbb R$ containing only irrational numbers. In fact, for any two real numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a<b$, there is a rational number $q$ such that $a<q<b$; in other words, the rationals are dense in $\mathbb R$.